# Is AsyncStorage permanent or temporary?

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I'm new with React Native and i would like to know after closing my application the AsyncStorage is clear or not. Is there any alternatives for AsyncStorage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is AsyncStorage permanent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43273302/is-asyncstorage-permanent)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use AsyncStorage, your app is going to persist the data on the storage system that is global to the app.

You can see how it works and the methods available from the oficial's docs https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html#asyncstorage

Comment: What?... You say "if you close the app before storing it it wont clear it." That doesn't make sense, as there is nothing to clear before you've stored data.

Answer (score 12):

It does not clear the storage once the app is closed.

You can however clear the storage / cache withing settings -> apps.